# Can't connect NodeMCU to websockets server

Tags: websocket, tcp, arduino, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I am working on a project in which I need to connect NodeMCU to an online WebSocket Node.js server. The server is using socket.io. Now I am using a `WebsocketsClient.h` library in NodeMCU to connect to the server. I have confirmed that it is connecting to WiFi properly.

This is the code of NodeMCU:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

#include <WebSocketsClient.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#ifdef DEBUG_ESP_PORT
#define DEBUG_MSG(...) DEBUG_ESP_PORT.printf( __VA_ARGS__ )
#else
#define DEBUG_MSG(...)
#endif

WebSocketsClient webSocket;
WiFiClient client;

void webSocketEvent(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

    switch(type) {
      case WStype_CONNECTED:
            {
                Serial.print("[WSc] Connected to url: ");
                Serial.println((char *)payload);
                // send message to server when Connected
                webSocket.sendTXT("Connected");
            }
            break;
        case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
            Serial.println("[WSc] Disconnected!\n");
            Serial.print("Type: ");
            Serial.println(type);
                        break;
        case WStype_TEXT:
            Serial.print("[WSc] get text: ");
            Serial.println((char *)payload);
            // send message to server
            // webSocket.sendTXT("message here");
            break;
        case WStype_BIN:
            Serial.print("[WSc] get binary length: ");
            Serial.println(length);
           // hexdump(payload, length);

            // send data to server
            // webSocket.sendBIN(payload, length);
            break;
    }

}
int led = 13;
char *ssid1 = "Rishab's Galaxy M31";
char *pass1 = "ciqk4548";

char *ssid2 = "dugar 4g";
char *pass2 = "rishab0430";

char path[] = "/";
char host[] = "robota-lock.herokuapp.com";

void setup()
{
    // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(115200);

    Serial.println("Starting up...");
    DEBUG_MSG("bootup...\n");

    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

    // Disconnect from an AP if it was previously connected
    // WiFi.disconnect();
    Serial.println("Connecting WiFi ");

    WiFi.begin(ssid2, pass2);
    Serial.print("connecting.");
    
   
    while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
      delay(125);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
      delay(125);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
      delay(125);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
      delay(125);
      Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("");
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    Serial.println("connected");

    Serial.print("IP Address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    WiFi.setAutoReconnect(true);
    WiFi.persistent(true);
    
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    Serial.print("Starting Socket Connection...");

    webSocket.beginSSL(host, 81);
    webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);

}


void loop()
{ 
    delay(3000);
    webSocket.loop();
    DEBUG_MSG("loop %d\n", millis());
    // delay(3000);
}
```

Now as you can see I am currently using Port 81. Whenever I use port 81 or 83, I get the same error:

```
23:06:59.419 -> BSSL:connect: Unable to connect TCP socket
23:06:59.419 -> loop 309059
23:07:02.912 -> [WSc] Disconnected!
```

And whenever I use 443 or 80 as Port, I get the following error:

```
23:11:17.769 -> loop 117716
23:11:21.279 -> [WSc] Disconnected!
23:11:21.279 -> 
23:11:21.279 -> Type: 1
23:11:21.604 -> BSSL:_connectSSL: start connection
23:11:21.604 -> BSSL:Connection *will* fail, no authentication method is setup
23:11:36.650 -> BSSL:_run_until: Timeout
23:11:36.650 -> BSSL:_wait_for_handshake: failed
23:11:36.650 -> BSSL:Couldn't connect. Error = 'Unknown error code.'
```

Either way, I cannot get it to connect to NodeMCU. Please help.

Comment: Then you have to use socketIOclient: https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets/blob/master/examples/esp8266/WebSocketClientSocketIO/WebSocketClientSocketIO.ino

Comment: `WiFiClientSecure client;`

Comment: @Juraj I am not even using `WiFiClient client`. I commented that part out. Are you saying I should use it? If yes, then can you please explain more.

Comment: @C1sc0 I tried that earlier, it didn't work either